# how to convert Date and time column of dataframe to datetime format of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DateTime column in my dataframe df as shown below:

```
   DateTime
3/1/2016 12:15:00 AM    
3/1/2016 12:30:00 AM    
3/1/2016 12:45:00 AM    
3/1/2016 1:00:00 AM 
3/1/2016 1:15:00 AM 
3/1/2016 1:30:00 AM 
3/1/2016 1:45:00 AM 
3/1/2016 2:00:00 AM     
3/1/2016 2:15:00 AM
```

I would like to convert it into the following format, i.e. 24 hours format as shown below:

```
03-01-2016 12:15:00
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print (df)
               DateTime
0  3/1/2016 12:15:00 AM
1  3/1/2016 12:30:00 AM
2  3/1/2016 12:45:00 AM
3   3/1/2016 1:00:00 AM
4   3/1/2016 1:15:00 AM
5   3/1/2016 1:30:00 AM
6   3/1/2016 1:45:00 AM
7   3/1/2016 2:00:00 AM
8  3/1/2016 2:15:00 PM  <-date is changed for better testing

df.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime)
print (df)
             DateTime
0 2016-03-01 00:15:00
1 2016-03-01 00:30:00
2 2016-03-01 00:45:00
3 2016-03-01 01:00:00
4 2016-03-01 01:15:00
5 2016-03-01 01:30:00
6 2016-03-01 01:45:00
7 2016-03-01 02:00:00
8 2016-03-01 14:15:00
```

EDIT:

Then need parameter `errors='coerce'` for replace problematic values to `NaT`:

```
print (df)
               DateTime
0  3/1/2016 28:15:00 AM <- wrong date
1  3/1/2016 12:30:00 AM
2  3/1/2016 12:45:00 AM
3   3/1/2016 1:00:00 AM
4   3/1/2016 1:15:00 AM
5   3/1/2016 1:30:00 AM
6   3/1/2016 1:45:00 AM
7   3/1/2016 2:00:00 AM
8  3/1/2016 2:15:00 PM 


df.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime, errors='coerce')
print (df)
             DateTime
0                 NaT
1 2016-03-01 00:30:00
2 2016-03-01 00:45:00
3 2016-03-01 01:00:00
4 2016-03-01 01:15:00
5 2016-03-01 01:30:00
6 2016-03-01 01:45:00
7 2016-03-01 02:00:00
8 2016-03-01 14:15:00
```

For checking problematic values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime, errors='coerce').isnull()])
                DateTime
0  3/1/2016 28:15:00 AM
```

Comment: Thanks i tried this but I'm getting this error: ValueError: Unknown string format.

Answer (score 4):

This should work :

```
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"],errors="coerce").dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

print (df["DateTime"])
```

Output:

```
0    01-03-2016 00:15:00
1    01-03-2016 00:30:00
2    01-03-2016 00:45:00
3    01-03-2016 01:00:00
4    01-03-2016 01:15:00
5    01-03-2016 01:30:00
6    01-03-2016 01:45:00
7    01-03-2016 02:00:00
8    01-03-2016 02:15:00
Name: DateTime, dtype: object
```